# JQuery send ajax through functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have got this function in my JQuery code

```
function sendAjax(postName,value){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {postName: value},
            success:function(a){
                alert(a)
            }
        })
    }
```

Now when i call it like this

```
sendAjax("borrow",send);
```

Instead of replacing `postName` with "borrow" it sends `postName`.How can i make it send what is given in the variable `postName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to first create the object, then use bracket notation for the dynamic key

```
function sendAjax(postName,value){
    var obj = {}

    obj[postName] = value;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: obj,
        success:function(a){
            alert(a)
        }
    })
}
```

Alternatively, use ES6 [object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) in browsers that support it

```
data: {[postName]: value},
```